# RAID 5, 2 out of 4 disk drives are foreign

Tags: raid5

I am in hot water and badly need help.

Server Machine is Dell PowerEdge r730. It has 4 hard drives of 1TB.

RAID 5 was already configured (Not by me).

Now I see this screen at startup. [image]

When I press any key, the health manager opens.

I see it says virtual drive failed. The physical drives shows First and 4th as Foreign while 2nd and third are Online.

What should I do?

PS: I tried this without any success: https://tycoonrp.wordpress.com/2017/09/13/poweredge-r230-uefi-drivers-issues-and-l2l3-error-mesage/

Comment: R5...on 1TB disks....in 2019 - wow, just rebuild using R1/10/6/60 and restore from backup

Comment: @Chopper3, I am not a system expert, so I don't know what is the best. The Server is configured by someone who left the company. Please can you elaborate how to do it. I've no backups. I'll really appreciate your help please. (I need the data on the disks, and it is not booting)

Comment: If you lost 2 drives in Raid 5, your data is gone, unfortunately.

Comment: No backups... in 2019. I'm at a loss to understand how this is still happening in 2019. Call Dell technical support and see if they can help you recover the array... if that's even possible. If not, and if the data is business critical then STOP doing anything with the server and contact a data recovery company.

Comment: Someone (joeqwerty for example) should write up their comment as an answer below. In case others with similar RAID failures find this question.

Comment: Thanks all for reply... @joeqwerty, I've contacted the data recovery company. You may post it as answer so I can close the thread...